# Unwind segue from tableview cell present in SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swrevealviewcontroller

I am new to storyboard and was implementing the unwind segue with SWRevealViewController and have the following issue

I have `RightRevealViewController` (which is embedded with the SWRevealViewController and marked as sw_right in the Main storyboard) it has a tableview, I would like to perform an unwind segue on the hit of its 3rd cell which says "Logout" On the click of logout i would like to navigate back to the `LoginViewController` screen.

So after reading lot of tutorials I came to know that I need to add a unwind segue action method in the login view controller since that's the view where i want to navigate back to so i added the below code inside the login view controller

```
 @IBAction func prepareForUnwind(segue: UIStoryboardSegue){
}
```

I have added the selection action on the table view cell but the issue is whenever i tap any cell i get navigated back to the login view whereas i want to have this navigation on the selection of third cell.

So As of now on my `RightRevealViewController` I have a table delegate method where i am identifying which cell index was clicked by the user and have added the below code

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if tableView == fixedTableContent{
        if indexPath.row == 2{
            [self .performSegueWithIdentifier("LoginScreen", sender: self)]
        }
    }
}
```

Also when the animation while this navigation is done is not smooth to be more clear I have broken it down in steps

1. The right slide navigation hides first
2. I see my front view controller
3. There is a lag of one second
4. Then i navigate / unwind to the login view

Is this behavior normal I mean it should directly take me to the login view controller am i missing something here, Please guide me out on how to resolve this i.e the conditional unwind segue with `UITableView` and the behavior that i am getting when i unwind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue and all i had to do was before the navigation call the `revealToggleAnimated` method

```
self.revealViewController().revealToggleAnimated(true)
self.revealViewController().navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

Doing this resolved the lag issue which i was facing

Answer (score 0):

if your login screen is root view then just use

[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]

Comment: I have already tried that but still i am getting the issue that i have posted above